# How to add cloud job function on Parse.com with different functions

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a main.js file uploaded to my parse cloud code. Currently main.js has the SMS Verification code in it. I need to upload the delete files cloud job but it accepts only main.js I have uploaded delete.js and used it as require(cloud/delete.js) in main.js file but it still doesn't detect the Cloud Job. How can I use the delete.js file for cloud job

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteMessages", function(request, status) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var ts = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var tsYesterday = ts - (3600);
    var dateYesterday = new Date(tsYesterday*1000);
    var query = new Parse.Query("AroundMe");
    query.lessThan("createdAt", dateYesterday);
    query.find({
        success: function(result) {
            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                result[i].destroy({
                    success: function(object) {
                        status.success("Delete job completed");
                        alert('Delete Successful');
                    },
                    error: function(object, error) {
                        status.error("Delete error :" + error);
                        alert('Delete failed');
                    }
                });
            }
            status.success("Delete job completed");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("Error in delete query error: " + error);
            alert('Error in delete query');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I figured out added this code into main.js and it worked!

Comment: The open source ParseServer is not support this. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Compatibility-with-Hosted-Parse#jobs

Comment: @ChunTingLin I am using Parse Backend still